# Using JavaScript / jQuery to populate modal content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a calendar widget that uses jQuery's load() function to populate the content of the event modal. The example can be found [here](https://codyhouse.co/gem/schedule-template/).

For the purposes of my calendar system, the modal content is generated on the same page as the calendar, where as the example has the modal content in a separate file.

The function that populates the modal is this:

```
this.modalBody.find('.event-info').load(event.parent().attr('data-content')+'.html .event-info > *', function(data){
        //once the event content has been loaded
        self.element.addClass('content-loaded');
    });
```

where the `.attr('data-content')+'.html .event-info > *',` is the content in the html file.

For my project, I have the modal content in a div with a PHP generated ID like so:

```
<div id=\"shift-".($i+1)."\" class=\"event-modal-content-form\">
    <p>This is the modal content</p>
</div>
```

The `event-modal-content-form` class is a simple class that just hides the div so it doesn't obstruct the calendar formatting.

So, I need to change the javascript to populate the modal with the content of this div rather than what the code is searching for now, and I've tried several different methods.

Right now what I have is:

```
this.modalBody.find('.event-info').getElementById(.attr('data-content')), function(data){
        //once the event content has been loaded
        self.element.addClass('content-loaded');
    });
```

But I get an unexpected token error for the `.attr` in `getElementById()`

Any pointers in the right direction would be immensely helpful.

Comment: That is invalid JavaScript. Learn JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I'm self taught\*, which is why I'm asking. I don't know what the proper syntax is and I can't seem to find a working solution. \*(I'm not anywhere close to proficient, I can do basic stuff right now, but I'm still learning)

Comment: It is not a question of being self-taught (I figure almost all JavaScript programmers are essentially self-taught) it is simply understanding what each construct does. `f(.p)` is invalid syntax. It is essentially nonsense. Also, you should get some tools, for example JavaScript syntax aware text editors, linters, IDEs.

Comment: This is nice, but it still doesn't help me. I'm using Sublime to edit everything, and I use the chrome dev tools to track errors and problems. I know what I wrote is wrong, but I don't know enough to fix it, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not? There is only one way you can resolve this issue: learning JavaScript.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I'm saying I've exhausted my other resources. I've read through other stackoverflow pages, I've read through documentation, and I've tried to debug, but I can't figure out how to properly implement this, which is why I'm asking people here for help. Frankly, you're not being helpful at all.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. `f(.p)` produces the syntax error you have mentioned and there is no advice that can help.

Comment: @gm-web Simply put, your problem is that you're trying to call a function `.attr` inside a constructor inside of another which makes no sense and causes an error. Also, what makes no sense is you calling `.find('.event-info').getElementById`. First you find all elements with class `event-info` then on that array you search for element with specific id where you pass a function? Maybe just get rid of the call to `getElementById` completely.

Comment: I'm editing this javascript based on the original calendar example (at the top of the question) and since I'm not sure how to solve this problem, and i'm not 100% sure how the javascript for the modal works to begin with, I'm not sure what to change the code to.